# How can I make clang-format put the first arg/param on its own line when arguments are split into lines?

Tags: c++, clang-format

I have the following `.clang-format` settings (among others, but these are the relevant ones AFAIK):

```
AlignAfterOpenBracket: 'DontAlign'
AllowAllParametersOfDeclarationOnNextLine: 'false'
BinPackArguments: 'false'
BinPackParameters: 'false'
```

What `clang-format` does (and similar for function calls):

```
void this_is_a_function(int first_param,
    int second_param,
    int third_param);
```

What I want it to do:

```
void this_is_a_function(
    int first_param,
    int second_param,
    int third_param);
```

I.e., I want to keep all the parameters/arguments left aligned, but I don't want to align everything to the open paren. Is this possible?

Comment: https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html

Comment: I'm aware of the full list of options. Which set of options achieves the desired result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a totally satisfactory answer, but better than nothing: add an empty line comment after the open parenthesis.

```
void this_is_a_function( //
    int first_param,
    int second_param,
    int third_param);
```

This forces clang-format to align the first item with the others.